# Replace backslash in string

Tags: java, regex, string, exception, replace

I have a `String` in which I am trying to replace the number enclosed by two backslashes.  For example: `\10\`  , I am trying to replace that with `10`.  I am currently using this regex to do that:

```
String texter = texthb.replaceAll("\\.+\\", "\\"+String.valueOf(pertotal + initper)+"\\");
```

This line is giving the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 4
```

.+\

I know it is because the regex is wrong.  What is the proper way to accomplish this?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you just need to remove all back slashes, you can simply write `texter = textbh.replace("\\", "");`

Comment: In code:  `"\\\\.+\\\\"` In variable: `\\.+\\ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use four backslashes to match a single backslash character.

```
String texter = texthb.replaceAll("\\\\.+?\\\\", "\\\\"+String.valueOf(pertotal + initper)+"\\\\");
```

Comment: With that I get the error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: character to be escaped is missing

Comment: That works thanks so much.  I will mark you as correct when it allows me.